# How to extract text from an script result

Tags: javascript

I am using this script to get the visitor's country name:

```
<script src="http://www.seocentro.com/cgi-bin/promotion/geo/geocn.pl" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This `geocn.pl` url returns:

```
document.write('<a href="http://www.seocentro.com/tools/online/ip-country.html" style="text-decoration: none;">SomeCountryName</a>');
```

What should I use next to obtain a `window.alert` with the name of the country?

```
window.alert(country);
```

Comment: It would appear that seocentro want to use a anchor tag linked back to their website since you are using their service "Understandable and fair". They also have a very polite message **IMPORTANT: Please DO NOT modify the code, otherwise we can not guarantee the correct working of this tool!** I would read that as "If you want to use our geo service please link back to our website" Hence setting it up to create a anchor tag linking back to the site and not just displaying the geo data. I'm sure you find many geo API's that are free and do not require anchor tags to the source.

Comment: @NewToJS, thanks for notifying I just read the message on http://www.seocentro.com/tools/promotion/country-display.html .. answer deleted

Comment: @Mi-Creativity very welcome! I always check the source for things like this before answering due to people trying to go against the terms of use. I'm not sure if that's why you were down voted though but that would be my guess as to why.

Comment: That message really doesn't matter here. The "Api Link" just returns a `document.write`. You can do whatever you want with that, even if it's just getting the result from it. It just says that they're not responsible for inaccurate results if you don't literally copy the code.

Comment: Not the down vote thing as it could be up voted by the OP or other users but to be honest I never check about such resources when users post their question and you were correct this violates their rights and we shouldn't support this violation

Comment: @Mi-Creativity: I downvoted that answer because the whole problem the OP has, is to get the returned string into a variable. Your answer didn't answer that.

Comment: Oh got your point now but the OP doesn't say this anywhere in the question though

Answer (score -2):

Use below code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    alert($("a:first").text());
});
</script>
```

Comment: I added this code next to mine but is not working. No alert is showing.

Comment: That's due to the lack of detail in the answer. This uses jQuery which isn't tagged in the question.